# Spring Java @DateTimeFormat

Tags: java, datetime, spring-mvc

I have created a helper to parse time froma webservice and output inanother format 
using @DateTimeFormat. However in my jsp view this is not formatted. Am I using this wrong?

```
 @Component
public class DateParserHelper {

    @DateTimeFormat(style="F-")
    public Date getFormattedDate() {
        return formattedDate;
    }


    public void setFormattedDate(Date formattedDate) {

        this.formattedDate = formattedDate;
    }


    public Date formattedDate;

    public void setDate(String date) throws ParseException {

        DateFormatter dateFormatter = new DateFormatter("y-M-d");
        setFormattedDate( dateFormatter.parse(date, UK));

    }





}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using JSTL in your jsp, you could use formatDate to format your date :

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${yourDate}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
```

Comment: I would rather the date was presented to the view in a particular format. But I will give it a go thanks.

Comment: After still failing to get @dateTimeFormat to work I went with this thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
String pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy";

...

public void setDate(String date) {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
    setFormattedDate(format.parse(date));
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I was hoping to retain the Spring stuff although I am aware of SimpleDateFORMAT