# jquery datepicker spring mvc date format

Tags: jquery, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jquery-ui-datepicker

When I save an object with datepicker that it is ok. But when I try to update I face problems. During update hibernate return date object like 2012-3-4 and this get into jquery datepicker field. Date picker field doesn't know the this format and during update date is not saved because the date format is incorrect. jquery date format is mm/dd/yyyy. I want to keep this format in datepicker.

What should I do?

jquery

```
$( "#event_end_date" ).datepicker();
```

.jsp

```
 <f:input path="activity.eventDate" type="text" style="width: 90%"/>
```

controller part

```
    @RequestMapping("/activity/{id}")
public String updateActivity(Model model, @PathVariable Long id) {
    Activity activity =  (Activity) databaseDao.load(id, Activity.class);
    ActivityVO act = new ActivityVO();
    act.setActivity(activity);
    model.addAttribute("activityVO", act);
    return "activity/create-activity";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I followed http://ankeetmaini.wordpress.com/2012/01/24/binding-date-in-spring/
It solved the problem

```
@InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder webDataBinder) {
             SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
             dateFormat.setLenient(false);
             webDataBinder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));
         }
```

Answer (score 3):

When working with Spring you have many possibilities to control date formatting. Personally i prefer CustomPropertyEditor, but you can give a chance to annotation driven formatting. 
Below list of my resources you can check:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html

[@DateTimeFormat not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827122/datetimeformat-not-working-properly)

[Spring Java @DateTimeFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885883/spring-java-datetimeformat)

[Spring MVC type conversion : PropertyEditor or Converter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544479/spring-mvc-type-conversion-propertyeditor-or-converter)